# Android StrictMode Thread Policy showing error

Tags: android

Actually I am trying to write an app having `minSDKversion:8` and `targetSDKversion:15` and I need to use

```
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

But its showing error

> StrictMode cannot be resolved to a type

I am using 2.2 SDK to compile my app

SOLVED:
We need atleast 2.3 to import StrictMode

Comment: `StrictMode` is available starting with `2.3` so you can't use it with `2.2` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So reposting the answer:

"StrictMode is available starting with 2.3 so you can't use it with 2.2"

**Credits goes to Luksprog**

Comment: But how to use 2.3 ? I have done min sdk target in manifest  to 9 ! but it doesnt helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tp = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
            }
```